# bootstrap-datepicker set date before 1970

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/) in a Django website.
Users have to choice their birth date with the widget.

The issue is that user can't choose a date before the January 1st 1970. Do you know any way to select date before 1970 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DatePicker javascript, you should have a section like this:

```
$('.datePickerClass').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '01/01/1960',
    endDate: '01/01/2099', 
    autoclose: true
});
```

The startDate property will specify the earliest date which can be picked (i.e. in this case 01/01/1960), with the same going for endDate.